# How to get accurate timestamp from a signal handler on a posix-conform way?

Tags: timestamp, signals, posix

*(Related [post](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/an-argument-for-the-unix-specific-programming-questions-site-quality) on meta)*

As we can see in signal (7), `gettimeofday()` isn't a reentrant function, thus it can't be used in signal handlers.

But I want to get the clock on a posix-conform way - for timestamping from signal handlers - which is more accurate as a second.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You might look at the ntp code, as it may need to do something similar.

Comment: Before another VtC, please read [this](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/an-argument-for-the-unix-specific-programming-questions-site-quality) related meta post.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Its signal handler does nothing interesting :-( (it only sets some global variables).

Comment: Why do you believe that gettimeofday() is not reentrant? I assume that gettimeofday() is not listed as async safe just because it is marked obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the man page [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), the POSIX 
function [`clock_gettime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) is listed as a safe function which can be called safely from a signal handler. And this function can provide a precise timestamp for your signals.

Comment: There is a difference between official standard text and reality in implementation. I see no reason for not listing gettimeofday() except that it is called outdated.  Using `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, tp)` may be a bad idea. Note that gettimeofday() is using a fast trap to gethrestime() and devides nanoseconds by 1000 on Solaris but clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, tp) is a normal "slow" syscall. An undocumented method on Solaris is to replace CLOCK_REALTIME by `__CLOCK_RELTIME0` to get a fast trap even with clock_gettime().